# jQuery get span value by class of parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get `<span>` value by class of parent element, which I think I made well, but it always throws me `undefined` ... What am I doing wrong please?
There is `<a>` which have class and inside that link is `<span>`, that value I need to get. Code is below, thank you!

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/pn60L93q/

```
    <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
        <span>
            I/37 Chrudim - obchvat, úsek křiž. I/17 - Slatiňany
        </span>
    </a>

<script>
    var currentConstructionName = $('a.chosen-single span').text();
    console.log(currentConstructionName);
</script>
```

Comment: did you added jquery library before your code?

Comment: **.html()** please

Comment: Something else is going on in your code-- if I copy that into a snippet with jQuery added it console logs "I/37 Chrudim - obchvat, úsek křiž. I/17 - Slatiňany" as expected.

Comment: @AlivetoDie sure, I did

Comment: @anied but everything else is working fine, I have no idea what could be wrong...

Comment: @HS1993  then it will work. check once my answer

Comment: @HoangHieu it also logs `undefined`

Comment: @HS1993 -- look at Alive To Die's answer.  He did exactly what I outlined above-- you can see in the snippet it is working.  So the answer to your question is that there's nothing wrong with the code as shown-- something else is going on.  Perhaps missing `$(document).ready` or jQuery as posited below, or perhaps some other JS error is short-circuiting your code before it reaches this point.

Comment: i just added jQuery to your fiddle example and it worked file , i think you might have other syntax issues , we need more information

Comment: @anied but I have jQuery already included, because I'm using other jQuery stuff and it works fine

Comment: Missing jQuery was one of many possibilities I listed.  You are confirming that you have jQuery included--- so it is something else.  But the problem is not in the question as posted-- that code executes fine.  I am afraid you are looking in the wrong place.  Perhaps there is another element matching `a.chosen-single span` that is beating out your selection.  Unfortunately, there is no way to tell from the code provided because that executes as expected.

Comment: @anied I think it could be because it's generated by gridator, so maybe it's not set yet, when I try to get its value..

Comment: I've not used Gridator, but that seems entirely possible-- you'll need to make sure your JS code isn't executing until the element definitely exists in the DOM, and you'll need to make sure that it is unique per the selector `a.chosen-single span`.

Comment: @anied so maybe just `delay()` could help? Or do you have any suggestion how to check if everything is ready?

Comment: @anied but now I tried to remove `.text()`  and I got this: `Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → list, selector: "a.chosen-single span" }`

Comment: Yes, so you are getting an empty return from jQuery-- ie, the element doesn't exist at the moment you search for it.  As for recommendations, that is much more specific to what exactly you are trying to accomplish, and the overall structure of your project.  Using a simple delay is not a robust solution because you have no guarantee as to how long before the element exists-- it's fragile and easily broken.  There might be an event fired from the library when it adds something to the DOM-- you could listen for it and then execute your code.  Maybe ask a new question specific to Gridator.

Comment: Your JS Fiddle is missing jQuery. As soon as I add it, it works fine.

Comment: @HS1993  if you got the answer then please mark the answer as accepted.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no syntax errors, your Jquery loaded.

Only problem I can think of is your document is not ready by then. Add it

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var currentConstructionName = $('a.chosen-single span').text(); 
    console.log(currentConstructionName);
    })
```

Comment: @HS1993  did you checked my answer

Answer (score 1):

**.html()** Worked ... Please check JSFIĐLE: `https://jsfiddle.net/pn60L93q/1/`

```
var currentConstructionName = $('a.chosen-single span').html();
console.log(currentConstructionName);
```